# Input field submitting last index, not index selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm dynamically populating a table from a databse (all of the `HTML` not included for brevity):

```
foreach($WOaccountsInfo as $WOInfo){
        $WOT .="<tr>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[1]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[2]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[3]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[4]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td><form method='post' action='/radiosite/other/index.php'>";
        $WOT .="<input type='hidden' value='$WOInfo[0]' name='ID' id='ID'>";
        $WOT .="<button type='submit' title='Edit'>Edit</button>";
        $WOT .= "<button type='submit' title='Delete' name='action' value='delWOEntry' onclick='confDel()'>Delete</button></td>";
        $WOT .="</tr>";
        }
```

Sending it the result to the controller like this:

```
$ID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$result = delWOentry($ID);
        if ($result === 1){
            header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=first&message=<p class='message'>The entry was successfully deleted from the database</p>");
            exit;
        } 
            else {
             header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=wopass&message=<p class='message'>Something went wrong with the deletion</p>");
            exit;
            }
```

The delete function code is here:

```
function delWOentry($ID) {
    $db = byuidahoradioconnect();
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM wideorbitaccounts WHERE ID = :ID';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowsChanged = $stmt->rowCount();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $rowsChanged;
}
```

And it does delete a row...but what it does is it deletes the last row in the SQL table.
In the web page, I've changed the input type from hidden to text, and on the page, it shows the correct ID number, but when I send it to the controller to be processed, the variable shows the ID number of the last row in the database.
So, in short, I'm trying to delete a row in my table based upon the ID of the row, but it is deleting the last row in the table instead of the row selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the form tag, so the forms end up nested with overlapping ID values.

```
foreach($WOaccountsInfo as $WOInfo){
        $WOT .="<tr>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[1]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[2]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[3]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td>$WOInfo[4]</td>";
        $WOT .="<td><form method='post' action='/radiosite/other/index.php'>";
        $WOT .="<input type='hidden' value='$WOInfo[0]' name='ID' id='ID'>";
        $WOT .="<button type='submit' title='Edit'>Edit</button>";
        // The following line is changed.
        $WOT .= "<button type='submit' title='Delete' name='action'
value='delWOEntry' onclick='confDel()'>Delete</button>
</form></td>"; // <-- Add </form> here
        $WOT .="</tr>";
        }
```

I added some line breaks to make it easier to see the change.

Comment: I was driving back to the office from the gym when I saw the notification thinking "there's no way I didn't close the form...", but I didn't, and closing it saved the code! Thank you sir!